# How to backup/restore docker image for deployment?

Tags: docker

I have an image to be updated with following command before each deployment.

```
$docker pull myusername/myproject:latest
```

This command overwrites the previous image.
How can I backup this image (or change it  to a different tag locally without committing to networking repository?  If there is anything wrong, I can restore the backup.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

> How can I backup this image

Simply use the [docker save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) command. `$ docker save myusername/myproject:latest | gzip -c > myproject_img_bak20141103.tgz`

You will later be able to restore it with the [docker load](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/) command. `gunzip -c myproject_img_bak20141103.tgz | docker load`

---

> or change it to a different tag locally without committing to networking repository?

Use the [docker tag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/) command: `$ docker tag myusername/myproject:latest myusername/myproject:bak20141103`

Comment: But what if I changed the container locally and committed to the image ( not pushed though), then  it shows this error message https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535790/how-do-i-use-docker-save-to-backup-a-local-image-to-file/45536545#45536545

Comment: FYI the links to [docker save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/), [docker load](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/) and [docker tag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/) have changed

Answer (score 9):

For completeness: For Docker on Windows the following syntax applies:

`docker save -o container-file-name.tar mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809`

`docker load -i "c:\path\to\file.tar"`

Answer (score 1):

Example.

#environment: bash shell

#id container: 1d09068efad1

#name backup: backup01

```
docker commit -p  1d09068efad1 backup01
docker save -o backup01.tar backup01
```

https://www.baculasystems.com/blog/docker-backup-containers/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/backing-up-a-docker-container/