# How do I use Docker save to backup a local image to a file?

Tags: docker, save

I want to backup my docker image, named `tt`, so I can change the base device size from 10 GB to 15 GB.

To do this I want to backup my local image first. But I am getting an error

```
$ sudo docker save -o tt.tar.gz tt
Error response from daemon: could not verify layer data for: sha256:xxxxx. This may be because internal files in the layer store were modified. Re-pulling or rebuilding this image may resolve the issue
```

My images:

```
$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY                     TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
tt                             latest              ced69d804781        13 minutes ago      9.186 GB
quay.io/travisci/travis-ruby   latest              e41062702ee0        2 years ago         5.782 GB
```

My containers:

```
$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
f6ce7cf223b3        quay.io/travisci/travis-ruby   "/bin/bash"         37 hours ago        Up 22 minutes       22/tcp              travis
```

The `tt` image is created from `quay.io/travisci/travis-ruby`. I installed some packages and committed it locally.

Comment: Stop the running image and then try. Though they are different but a shared layer may be causing an issue

Comment: @TarunLalwani I stopped my container, but it still shows the same error. http://i.imgur.com/Us5y0tg.png

Answer (score 2):

Commit the container again and then try saving it on the local system:

```
docker commit [CONTAINER-ID]
```

And then try to save it:

```
docker save -o tt.tar.gz tt:latest
```

Comment: Just tried, still not working.  Same error http://i.imgur.com/wkIrTHo.png

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the `tt` image with tag name test. *Try* doing with *latest*:

```
docker save -o tt.tar.gz tt:latest
```

Or alternatively you can do:

```
docker save tt:latest > tt.tar
```

Comment: sorry I pasted wrong commands in my question, they are modified now. I tried your commands,  it shows the same error.
http://i.imgur.com/GPgRuSs.png

Comment: try pushing it to your hub.docker.com repository 

    _docker login_ and then run  _docker push USER/tt_    

,USER is your docker hub username

Comment: Is there any way around it ? It's 9gb and my bandwidth is limited. ( I guess most probably it will work if I push it.)

Comment: Fair enough 9 GB is a large file ,and yes definitely it will work if you push it to hub, umm there is a way though , all your images get stored in local file system already I guess in /var/lib/docker you just have to find the correct directory and create your tar directly from there.

Comment: I have to check though , I will write another answer as soon as i confirm the procedure for doing it.

Comment: Hey can you once again commit the container , there are some changes made in your container , committing it again may resolve this error.