# docker unable to build/run with corporate vpn connected

Tags: docker

I have been using docker toolbox on windows 7 for a while, but I can't build my images or run docker containers when I am connected to cmy corporate network via a vpn connection.  I keep getting messages saying that the docker end--point cannot be found.

I know our corporate vpn connection blocks connections to lan resources that are outside of the corporate network like my home printer, or virtual machines running on my local computer.

Is there any way to allow docker to work in this kind of environment?

Answer (score 0):

Best option that I can think of is to have backup of the image in a tar file and place that file in a location which is accessible within your company. And then you can import from that file. Here are few useful links.

1. [Import from remote location](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/import/)
2. [Load image from tar](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/)
3. [Backup and restore image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26713032/6207775)